# (Sobject) '{!Record.Field__c}' is a picklist field.'Test' is an invalid field value

Tags: managed-package, picklist

Recently I have added a new value for a global value set that is being used in a picklist field for an sobject. The field is required, restricted, and has the new added value as the first and default.

After creating a beta package for my ISV including this metadata, upon upgrade, we are facing this error:

(Sobject) '{!Record.Field__c}' is a picklist field.'Test' is an invalid field value.

Do you know what may be the reason?

Comment: Check this blog it might contain the answer https://albasfdc.com/2017/08/16/global-picklists-and-managed-packages/

Comment: Does your object use record types? If yes, that picklist value might be missing in the record type configuration.

Comment: @Christoph it is not using record types. I have updated the question since it is actually upgrade, not install, so it has more sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global value sets are package upgradeable but new values will not be added automatically, If you have hard dependency to your new value in the picklist, such as using the new value in dynamic forms to adjust your layout visibility, it will cause problem upon package upgrade since the new value have to be added manually after upgrade.